# Add html tags within a var in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using code below for some animation. However I need to wrap the first words with a span so I can change the color of the first word. How would I go about adding a span?

Not strong in jQuery at all, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var num = 0;
    var words = [
        {left: "Slam Your Face", right: "Watch Out"},
        {left: "Death", right: "Death"}
     ];    

    var fadel = $('#fadeL');
    var fader = $('#fadeR');

    animate();

    function animate() {
        var leftword = words[num].left;
        var rightword = words[num].right;

    fadel
        .stop()
        .css('top', '18px')
        .css('left', '0')
        .css('opacity', 0)
        .text(leftword).show();

    fader
        .stop()
        .css('top', '68px')
        .css('left', '400px')
        .css('opacity', 0)
        .text(rightword).show();

    fadel.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: (350 - fadel.width()) + 'px'
        }, 3000, function() {
            fadel.fadeOut("fast", function() {
            queueNext();
        });
    });

    fader.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: '250px'
    }, 3000, function() {  
            fader.fadeOut("fast");
        });
    }

    function queueNext() {
        if (++num == words.length)
        num = 0;

        animate();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YxMHx/6/

```
$(function() {
    var num = 0;
    var someConditionIsTrue = true;
    var words = [
        {left: "Slam Your Face", right: "Watch Out"},
        {left: "Death", right: "Death"}
     ];    

    var fadel = $('#fadeL');
    var fader = $('#fadeR');

    animate();

    function animate() {
        var leftword = words[num].left;
        var rightword = words[num].right;

        var first = leftword.slice(0, leftword.indexOf(" "));

        first = "<span class=\"span_class\">" + first + "</span>";
        var lastWords = leftword.substring(leftword.indexOf(" ") + 1);

        var finalString = first + lastWords;


    fadel
        .stop()
        .css('top', '18px')
        .css('left', '0')
        .css('opacity', 0)
        .html(finalString).show().delay(2000);

    fader
        .stop()
        .css('top', '68px')
        .css('left', '400px')
        .css('opacity', 0)
        .text(rightword).show();

    fadel.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: (350 - fadel.width()) + 'px'
        }, 3000, function() {
            fadel.fadeOut("fast", function() {
            queueNext();
        });
    });

    fader.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: '250px'
    }, 3000, function() {  
            fader.fadeOut("fast");
        });
    }

    function queueNext() {

        if (++num == words.length)
        num = 0;

        animate();
    }

    queueNext();
});
```

Comment: That would change the color for the entire div. I'm looking only to change the color of the first word (Slam) from black to white.

Comment: i c... but the words are being brought in using vars. So how would that work?

Comment: You would set the `html` of the element using the `html` method from jQuery. And then you could wrap it. Or you could build the var with the `spans` already around it, and set the `html` from there.

Comment: That would be best... how would I build the var with spans already in it. var words = left: "<span class="loki">Slam</span> THis is"

Comment: @Jeff I'll build a quick example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27346/discussion-between-evan-and-jeff)

Answer (score 0):

```
function spanFirstWord(str) {
    return str.replace(/^(\w+)/, '<span class="first">$1</span>');
}

function animate() {
    var leftword = spanFirstWord(words[num].left);
    var rightword = spanFirstWord(words[num].right);

fadel
    .stop()
    .css('top', '18px')
    .css('left', '0')
    .css('opacity', 0)
    .html(leftword).show();

fader
    .stop()
    .css('top', '68px')
    .css('left', '400px')
    .css('opacity', 0)
    .html(rightword).show();

fadel.animate({
    opacity: 1,
    left: (350 - fadel.width()) + 'px'
    }, 3000, function() {
        fadel.fadeOut("fast", function() {
        queueNext();
    });
});
```

Comment: Added and edit the code as show by your example. However, rather than adding the span... it's just as if I've type <span class="first">.

Comment: Did you change `.text()` to `.html()` in the `animate()` function as I did?

Comment: Yeah. That was it. Thank you @Barmar for the help. Didn't realize I missed that part until I went over your example a few times. Thank you again.